# Adding new members in subclass in C#

Tags: c#, serialization, xmlserializer

```
namespace ClassesRa.Classes
{
    public class FicheLine
    {
        public int ItemRef { get; set; }
        public double Amount { get; set; }
        public string UnitCode { get; set; }
    }

    public class Fiche
    {
        public List<FicheLine> FicheLines { get; set; }
        public Fiche()
        {
            FicheLines = new List<FicheLine>();
        }
        public string ClientCode { get; set; }       
    }


    public class SalesFicheLine : FicheLine
    {
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
    }

    public class SalesFiche : Fiche
    {
        public List<SalesFicheLine> FicheLines { get; set; }
        public SalesFiche()
        {
            FicheLines = new List<SalesFicheLine>();
        }
        public string PayCode { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I want to derive SalesFiche from Fiche and add new members.
I want to derive SalesFicheLine from FicheLine and add new members.
I want to see SalesFicheLine in SalesFiche as FicheLine.
Is there a mistake or a defect in the above example?

```
namespace ClassesRa
{
    public partial class fMain : Form
    {
        public fMain()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void fMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SalesFiche f = new SalesFiche();
            f.ClientCode = "120.001";
            f.PayCode = "30";
            f.FicheLines.Add(new SalesFicheLine() { ItemRef = 1, Amount = 10, UnitCode = "PK", Price = 100 });

            string xmlString = SerializeToString(f);
        }

        public string SerializeToString(object obj)
        {
            string str = "";
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(obj.GetType());
            using (StringWriter writer = new StringWriter())
            {
                serializer.Serialize(writer, obj);
                str = writer.ToString();
            }
            return str;
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to convert it to XML with the `SerializeToString` function, it gives the following error :

> {"There was an error reflecting property 'FicheLines'."}

Thanks..

Comment: Better post the full exception, there will indicate the cause of the error.

Comment: What is the Inner Exception?

Answer (score 0):

You have to rename the property "FicheLines" in your SalesFiche class. I tested it with "SalesFicheLines". This will fix the crash.

I also recommend that you change your SaleFiche class to this

```
   public class SalesFiche : Fiche
    {
        public SalesFiche()
            :base()
        {
        }
        public string PayCode { get; set; }
    }
```

You already have access to FicheLines's FicheLines property, so there's really no need to create another FicheLines property in SalesFiche.